# Re Publish the kafka DLQ topics

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

After 2 retries my topic went to DLQ.

Is there any way to re-publish the dlq topics on demand(Manually using api)?

Here I am adding my code which will three apis

1) Will send the message and successfully consumed.

2) Will send the topic ans will throw error and finally will move to DLQ.

3) **Will try to read and publish topics from DLQ(Where I stuck).**

```
 public class KafkaProducerConfig {

private String bootstrapAddress="localhost:9092";

private String groupId = "dlq_topics_group";

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    return new  DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Object>(configProps);
}
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

}    

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

private String bootstrapAddress="localhost:9092";

private String groupId = "dlq_topics_group";

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template;

private Integer maxRetry = 3;

private Integer concurrency=1;

private Integer pollTimeout=1000;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
  factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecovererHandler(template), maxRetry));
  configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory());
  return factory;
}


@Bean
public KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> kafkaConsumer() {
    return new KafkaConsumer<(consumerFactory().getConfigurationProperties());
}
}    


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/kafka/controller")
public class KafkaController {

@Autowired
MessageService messageService;


@PostMapping(value="/send/{message}")
public void sendMessage1(@PathVariable String message) {
    messageService.sendMessage(message);
}

@PostMapping(value="/send-kafka-msg/{message}")
public void sendMessage(@PathVariable String message) {
    messageService.sendMessage(message);
}

@PostMapping(value="/resend-dlq-topic")
public void reprocessDLQTopics() {
**//LOGIC TO READ DLQ AND REPROCESS THE TOPICS**
    messageService.reprocessDLQTopics();
}
}


@Service
public class MessageService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageService.class);

private static final String TOPIC_EX = "kafka-msg-topic-ex";
private static final String TOPIC = "kafka-msg-topic";
private static final String DLQ_TOPICS = "dql_topics";
private static final String DLQ_NOTIFICATION_TOPIC = "dlq_notification_topic";

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

@Autowired
KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin;

@Autowired
KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> kafkaConsumer;

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    logger.info("sending message ", message);
    kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);

}

public void sendMessageEx(String message) {
    logger.info("sending message ", message);
    kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);
}

@KafkaListener(topics = { TOPIC, TOPIC_EX }, groupId = "group-id")
public void messageReciver(String message) {
    logger.info("message receiver" +kafkaAdmin.getConfig().entrySet().parallelStream().toString());
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

@KafkaListener(id = "DLQ_TOPICS_GROUP", topics = DLQ_TOPICS)
public void dltListen(String dlqMsg) {
    logger.info("Received from DLT: " + dlqMsg.toString());
}

public void reprocessDLQTopics() {
    **//LOGIC TO RE-PUBLISH DLQ TOPICS**
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "re-publish the dlq topics" but you can send a record to any topic (including the DLQ) using a `KafkaTemplate`.

If you mean consume from the DLQ topic and republish to the original topic then yes, you can do that too.

**EDIT**

Here is one solution:

```java
@Component
class Config {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so57157134", topics = "so57157134")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so57157134_DLT", topics = "so57157134_DLT", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listenDLT(String in) {
        System.out.println("Re-publish DLT");
        this.template.send("so57157134", in);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listenForIdleContainer(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        this.registry.getListenerContainer("so57157134_DLT").stop();
    }

    public void reprocessDLQTopics() {
        this.registry.getListenerContainer("so57157134_DLT").start();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so57157134", 10, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicDLT() {
        return new NewTopic("so57157134_DLT", 10, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

The only problem with it is what happens if you still have failures for the replayed records; the container will never go idle so you will be looping around forever. One solution to that would be to somehow detect the loop and stop the container in that condition as well.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to achieve. My requirement is if it fails it will go to DLQ and once the problem fixed, I have to read it again from DLQ and publish it using API.Thanks